# Visual Studio Online, continuous deployment of WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I've setup continuous deployment of a web job using Visual Studio Online.
The web job is running continuously using [Always On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatecontinuousacreate-a-continuously-running-webjob).

When the job is running, i get the following error message when vso tries to deploy a new build:

[image: Error]

..which makes sense to me, cause the job is running

Any idea, how to stop the running web job **before** a new release will be  deployed ?

Thanks in advance

regards!

**UPDATE 21.11.2016**

The job is deployed under **app_data/jobs/continuous/runner** where the Web Applikation itself is deployed under **wwwroot**

[image]

Comment: Are you meaning that you could deploy a new build successfully after you  stopping your WebJob on Azure Portal?  As I know, you could run your WebJob directly from the WebJob binaries directory, which could cause the original WebJob binaries being locked when redeploying the WebJob.

Comment: Hi Bruce! Exactly, as long the job is NOT running, continuous deployment works fine. But as soon the job runs (in my case while(true)), the deployment fails

Comment: Please try to have a look at this plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbengtsson.appservices-start-stop

Comment: Hi Bruce...unfortunately Azure App Services - Start and Stop is not compatible with the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Connection Type.